# Passing Meteor.settings to Bundled Meteor (with NginX and Passenger)

Tags: nginx, meteor, settings, passenger

I want to setup a multitenancy environment for MeteorJS apps using Nginx and Passenger.
I'm running Meteor as a bundled Node Application and my NginX site configuration contains multiple varieties of:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <<URL>>;
    root <<BUNDLE_DIR>>/public;

    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_set_cgi_param MONGO_URL <<MONGO URL>>;
    passenger_set_cgi_param ROOT_URL <<ROOT URL>>;

    #Meteor.settings
    passenger_set_cgi_param METEOR_SETTINGS '{ "public": { "tenant": "icter" } }';

    passenger_app_type node;
    passenger_startup_file main.js;

    passenger_min_instances 1;

}
```

If I do a console.log on the client side of Meteor.settings it is undefined. Any ideas on how I can pass/access the Meteor.settings within my app?

Comment: I've added a `console.log(process.env);` to the server-side code and it's passed on: 
`App 5622 stdout:   NODE_ENV: 'production',
App 5622 stdout:   PASSENGER_APP_ENV: 'production',
App 5622 stdout:   METEOR_SETTINGS: '{"public":{"tenant":"icter"}}'`, but my object within Meteor is still empty.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I'm running into the exact same issue :(

Comment: See my own answer below ;-) I've made the "public" settings available for the client through a meteor.method.

Answer (score 1):

The `Meteor.settings.public.tenant` was not available on the client side, but available on the server.

So I've changed it to `Meteor.settings.tenant` and made this available through a method (which is actually a better way, because in this case it corresponded with a configuration specific for this tenant). So with this setup I don't have to make the configurations for all the tenants available for the client, but just the tenant configuration.